# TNonblockingServer throws an assert while adding a user created event base

Tags: thrift

I am trying to create a TNonblockingServer and registering a user created event base with registerEvents method. registerEvents method throws an assert crashing the program. I am pasting the server code.

```
    int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    try 
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<AdderHandler> handler(new AdderHandler());
        boost::shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new AdderProcessor(handler));
        boost::shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());
        TNonblockingServer server(processor, protocolFactory, 9090);

        //create a foreign event loop 
        event_base *eb = event_base_new();
        struct event * es = evsignal_new(eb, SIGTERM, &sigtermHandler, eb);
        evsignal_add(es, NULL);

        //tell thrift to use it.
        server.registerEvents(eb);

        //Finally called serve
        server.serve();
    }
    catch(TTransportException &ex)
    {
        std::cerr<<"server exited with exception:"<<ex.what();
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

error message:

```
Thrift: Wed Dec 10 23:12:47 2014 TNonblockingServer: Serving on port 9090, 1 io threads.
Thrift: Wed Dec 10 23:12:47 2014 TNonblockingServer: using libevent 2.0.21-stable method epoll
Thrift: Wed Dec 10 23:12:47 2014 TNonblocking: IO thread #0 registered for listen.
Thrift: Wed Dec 10 23:12:47 2014 TNonblocking: IO thread #0 registered for notify.
server: src/thrift/server/TNonblockingServer.cpp:1199: void apache::thrift::server::TNonblockingServer::registerEvents(event_base*): Assertion `ioThreads_.empty()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but this could actually be a bug. Would you mind discussing this on the mailing list?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the TNonblockingServer, the serve() method registers a NULL for use event base right at the start. Commenting out the line TNonblockingServer.cpp:1257 , solved the problem. But i am not quite sure what i am screwing up.